# Failing to subclass builtin String object

Tags: javascript, subclassing, built-in, ecmascript-6

I've been experimenting with subclassing the built-in String object in ES2015 using Node 5.3.0. I'm running the code untranspiled using a bunch of harmony flags. Here's the full command: 
`node --harmony --harmony_modules --harmony_destructuring --harmony_rest_parameters --harmony_arrow_functions --harmony_spreadcalls --harmony_object --harmony_default_parameters --harmony_new_target --harmony_reflect --harmony_modules ~/t.js`

Given that the spec specifically says the String object is made to be subclassable (See section `21.1.1 The String Constructor`), I'm struggling to understand if this is something that I'm doing wrong or a bug in Node or maybe even V8.

The code to reproduce the issue follows:

```
'use strict';

class Str extends String {
  capitalize() {
    return `${this.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${this.slice(1)}`;
  }
}

var s = new Str('asdf');

console.log(s.constructor);
//[Function: String]

console.log(s.__proto__)
//[String: '']

console.log(s.capitalize());
//TypeError: s.capitalize is not a function
```

The code above demonstrates that the prototype chain isn't being setup as I would expect. However, if I manually fix the `__proto__` using the code below, everything works correctly.

```js
'use strict';

class Str extends String {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
  }

  capitalize() {
    return `${this.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${this.slice(1)}`;
  }
}

var s = new Str('asdf');
console.log(s.constructor);
//[Function: Str]

console.log(s.__proto__);
//Str {}

console.log(s.capitalize());
//Asdf
```

I'm really curious to know why the inheritance is not working as I'd expect.

Comment: you don't capture the passed argument in the first one

Comment: I can't answer about extending `String` but `this.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()` is wrong. You probably want `this.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()`.

Comment: funny thing, the first code works just fine in firefox...

Comment: @naomik What's wrong with `slice(0,1)`?

Comment: @RGraham oh duh. I was thinking as Strings as arrays of Chars where `"foo".slice(0,1)` would return `['f']` where `['f'].toUpperCase()` is broken/unintended. Wups :)

Comment: The ES6 spec does allow for subclassing built-ins, but engines still need to implement support. The [Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-miscellaneous_subclassables_String_is_subclassable) says it does support it under strict mode, but it doesn't because `s instanceof Str !== true`. So unfortunately it doesn't look like subclassing String is possible for the current version of Node

Comment: @dandavis, I don't need to capture it explicitly, ES6 calls the super constructor automatically when an inheriting constructor is not supplied.

Comment: @RGraham I suspect that could be the case, however, subclassing Array for example works as intended. The reason `instanceof`is failing is the incorrect prototype chain as I mention in the question. If you try `instanceof` on the second example it'll work correctly because I force the prototype chain to be correct.

Comment: @Steve Subclassing Array I think always gets more focus because it's slightly more complicated. I would be inclined to log this as a bug on the Node [issues page](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues)

Comment: I'm resisting opening this as an issue in Node because it could just be that Node 5.3.0 is using an incomplete/buggy version of V8 and it could already be resolved. OTH it could be something I don't know about inheriting from String.

Comment: Same result in the latest node v5.4.1.

Comment: I just tested it on v6.9.1 and it works.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ, indeed! It seems to have been a bug in V8, so my original answer is correct for fixing it in prior versions. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've yet to find a definitive answer to the question, but my quick and dirty solution has been working for the moment so I'll leave it as the answer for anyone who runs into the same problem.

You can fix the prototype chain when inheriting from the String built-in using the following line in your `constructor()`:

`Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);`

The `new.target.prototype` bit ensure that should you inherit further from your own type the prototype chain will continue to be correct.