# The error when extending String in ES6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

```js
 'use strict';

 class ReverseString extends String {
   reversed() {
     let res = '';
     for (let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
       res += this[i];
     }
     return res;
   }
 }

 let rs = new ReverseString("wangyang");
 console.log(rs.reversed());
```

when i run this code, i meet an error:

```
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop>node wy.js
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.js:14
console.log(rs.reversed());
               ^

TypeError: rs.reversed is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop\wy.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3
```

I can't find the root cause for this error.

the output of `console.log(rs);` is `String {0: "w", 1: "a", 2: "n", 3: "g", 4: "y", 5: "a", 6: "n", 7: "g", length: 8, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "wangyang"}]`.

Here is my node version:

```
C:\Users\elqstux\Desktop>node -v
v5.3.0
```

Comment: This question [has already been raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605185/failing-to-subclass-builtin-string-object). Basically Node does not fully support subclassing built-ins. The main problem is that it never really creates an `instanceof ReverseString`. Node just sees `rs` as a `String`

Answer (score 2):

`String` is currently not subclassable in Node 5.3, according to:

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-miscellaneous_subclassables

Your example should work fine on Firefox 45+ and Edge 13+

Comment: I can confirm, that it doesn't work in Webkit, but it works in Edge!

Comment: Says *Flag: support for this feature incorrectly requires strict mode*. It doesn't actually work with any flag, or strict mode

Comment: @RGraham That's probably because Node 5 does not support `class` outside strict mode.